# How can i start laragon services at windows startup?

Tags: laragon

When laragon is not started as administrator, apache and mysql generates arror as the picture below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voTW9.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxJjz.png)

I have tried to do start automatically but does not work